# Finding the area under a speed time graph

Tags: integration

I recently learned about integration and I wondered how it could be applied to a speed time graph since it does not have a particular equation of a line that one can integrate. Do you split it into parts? I have heard of a type of integration which specialises in putting shapes under th graph to find the area so that might be the answer. An example of one can be something like this :

[image: https://danpearcymaths.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/picture15.png]

Thanks for the clarification

Gedr

Edit : I'm mainly interested in points C to D since all others are basically triangles.

Comment: but it is a x-t graph, area under v-t graph gives you the displacement. and slope at any point on this x-t graph will give the velocity at that point.

Comment: Oh so you can't find the equation of the whole thing but only sections? How about this one http://gauss.vaniercollege.qc.ca/pwiki/images/e/e8/Ex_Graph_xt_4_a.png?

Comment: area under x-t graph gives you nothing!

Comment: Huh. I though the area under a speed time graph gives you distance. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, area under speed time graph gives distance. but all of your graphs are x-t that is, "distance time graphs"

Comment: Oh ok I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This graph is a Position(time), it's antiderivative will give you the [absement](http://wearcam.org/absement/examples.htm).

To calculate the area under this graph you can separate into these subregions:

[[image: hi]]

Then each area is just a simple geometric figure, for the rectangles you use the very well known formula $base\cdot height$ and for the triangles $ \dfrac {base\cdot height} 2$.

Notice, however, that to calculate the area under the curved region, we need the formula that describes the position in that timeframe.

E: I didn't see your edit, we can approximate that area without knowing the formula splitting that region into smaller rectangles, triangles, etc.